# Partitioned SSD: one partition approaching 75%

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd

I have a SSD on a Windows laptop that I partitioned to create a Linux dual boot. As I found I rarely used the Windows side, I partitioned off another siice of Windows and bind mounted it to my `/home` directory.

Now that extra slice, the home partition, is approaching 75% -- which I've heard is the point at which SSD performance degrades (maybe false).

Is it worth the work to merge the two Linux partitions? I am backed up so data loss is not an issue.

Comment: How old is your SSD? From what I've heard, most "good" SSDs already have invisible extra capacity (over-provisioning) so they're not full even if the "visible" space is at 100%...

Comment: @grawity It's a Samsung 500G NVME in an Asus NV01VW that I bought in 2016 Any extra space is a temporary solution though, so I'm still looking at the question.

Comment: The SSD doesn’t know about partitions.

Comment: @DanielB Ah. So the 75% rule is a good rule? But it applies to the total space used.